# Помогите с 404 ошибкой в python Django!

Tags: python, django, http-status-code-404

Очень туповатый конечно вопрос...Но из-за чего(из-за какого файла) у меня ошибка 404,я знаю что это такое,просто не могу понять в каком файле я написал что-то не так...

Вот сама ошибка:

Страница не найдена (404)
Метод запроса:  ПОЛУЧИТЬ

URL запроса:    http://127.0.0.1:5000/first/

Используя URLconf, определенный в first.urls, Django попробовал эти шаблоны URL в следующем порядке:
NewsApp /
админ /
Текущий путь first/не соответствует ни одному из них.

Вы видите эту ошибку, потому что DEBUG = Trueв вашем файле настроек Django есть. Измените это на False, и Django отобразит стандартную страницу 404.

Вот код главного URLS.PY(да и еще у меня есть приложение под названием newsapp):

```
from django.contrib import admin
from django.urls import path,include


urlpatterns = [
    path('newsapp/',include('newsapp.urls')),
    path('admin/', admin.site.urls),
]
```

Вот код URLS.PY в приложении:

```
from django.urls import path

from . import views

urlpatterns = [
    path('', views.index, name = 'index')
]
```

Вот код VIEWS.PY в приложении:

```
from django.http import HttpResponse

def index(request):
    return HttpResponse('Просто строка!')
```

ПОМОГИТЕ ПОЖАЛУЙСТА!

Comment: Если надо скину еще файлы

Comment: В ваших urls.py не задано соответствие тому url'у который вы запрашиваете. С чего вы взяли, что что-то должно откликнуться на `/first`?

Comment: Спасибо огромное!Затупил на такой просто ошибке...